# Two uitableviewcell separator appears for each cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

[image]

Please have a look at the picture attached. The tableview cell has two cell separators. How is this even possible?

If i set tableview separator style as None, one separator disappears. The other remains there always!

I never knew one cell can have two separators.

Comment: This is from the 'Capture View Hierarchy'. And not from interface builder.

Comment: Can i do that? Im sorry. I never knew that. Can you help me how to do it?

Comment: @snob-z did you solve this?

Comment: @slxl I just deleted the file and created again! It started working fine

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem occured in `UITableView` with static cells.

I had a cell with zero height right under the one that showed two separators  in captured view hierarchy and the separator somehow moved to this cell.

So the solution is removing any static cells with zero height or modify separator inset so the separator is not visible.